# GetDirectory based on getDirectory

Tags: c#, foreach, directoryinfo, getdirectories

I have an application that needs to return the names of subdirectories in a specific path.  However, the path can include a variable, and towards the end of the path, I want it to check a certain folder.

My current code is something like

```
string path = "\\\\" + computerList + "\\C$\\Program Files (x86)\\blah1\\blah2\\";
string searchPattern = "*_*";

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] directories =
    di.GetDirectories(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

followed by

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
{
   versionInformation.Add(computerList+" "+dir.Parent.Parent.Parent+" "+dir.Parent + " " + dir.Name);
}
```

What I **want** it to do is take the results from the directory search - and then add `\\working\\products\\` and iterate through that full list/path.

So - in short - I want the versionInformation list to end up being
Directory information up to `blah2\` - I want it to find the folder after blah2 (which it does) but then I want to append the `\\working\\products\\` and use that entire path for what it ends up searching for the `*_*` in.

*EDIT*  I just realized that I may have been addressing this the wrong way - It appears that my current code actually works - But when it lists the directory names, for some reason, It comes out wrong...

```
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
        {

            //DirectoryInfo threeLevelsUp = dir.Parent.Parent.Parent;
            versionInformation.Add(computerList+" "+dir.Parent.Parent.Parent+" "+dir.Parent + " " + dir.Name);
            //Console.WriteLine(dir.Parent + " " + dir.Name);
        }
    var beautifyList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, versionInformation);
    MessageBox.Show(beautifyList);
```

The first iteration for (using the below folders as an example) ICanBeDifferent will result in the FIRST item found being labeled as "ICanBeDifferent", but the SECOND result (for something found under ICanBeDifferent) would return FunTimes as the parent.parent.parent.

What could be causing this?!
Example Folders
C:\Program Files (x86)\LLL\Funtimes\ICanBeDifferent\Working\Products\Superman\2015_2_0_7

C:\Program Files (x86)\LLL\Funtimes\ICanBeDifferent\Working\Products\Office\2015_2_2_43

C:\Program Files (x86)\LLL\Funtimes\ThisIsWhatChanges\Working\Products\Lanyard\2015_2_0_70

Comment: Can you give an example of some folders to make your question more understandable?

Comment: Depends on starting directories `SearchOption.AllDirectories` can get you an error. Better, write recursive function to go through one dir at the time with try-catch

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like you want the [Path.Combine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and use it like

```
string resultDir = Path.Combine(dir, "..\\working\\products");
```

if `dir` is a string or

```
string resultDir = Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "..\\working\\products");
```

if `dir` is a DirectoryInfo.